# Upgrade to PHP 7.4.1 in Ubuntu CI Appication throwing Error. Why?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.4

Just upgraded to PHP 7.4.1 
followed by : https://dev.to/pushkaranand/upgrading-to-php-7-4-26dg

After upgrade,

Code-igniter application throwing error like :

```
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Filename: /var/www/html/CI_PROJECT/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
```

Tried : By uncommentating below line in php.ini (/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini):

```
extension=mysqli 
extension=/path/to/extension/mysqli.so
mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
```

Then, did

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Please guide me with appropriate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This :

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql
```

Then, in Router.php file

```
/var/www/html/CI_PROJECT/application/third_party/MX/Router.php         

 // if (strpos($class, $suffix) === FALSE)
 if( $suffix && strpos($class, $suffix) === FALSE)
```

And in Modules.php File

```
/var/www/html/CI_PROJECT/vv_project/application/third_party/MX/Modules.php

// (is_array($module)) ? list($module, $params) = each($module) : $params = NULL;   
(is_array($module)) ? list($module, $params) = [key($module), current($module)] : $params = NULL;
```